# StartScan() and StopScan() for lower APIs

Tags: android, java.util.scanner

The methods `StartLeScan`() and `StopLeScan()` in the class BluetoothAdapter have been deprecated and removed from Android Library.The new methods `startscan()` and `stopscan()` support only API > 21. Could you please tell me about any alternative methods to scan for an I beacon and obtain its Proximity UUID for  APIs lower than 21 as well?

Comment: You can check current api level in device with a simple if else statement. If(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT< Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) StartLeScan()... Else startScan()...

Comment: I tried that also, but in vain. I am using Android Studio 1.3.1 and installed the SDK platforms for lower APIs as well.. But, when I am trying to run it, The App is stopping midway.I am not getting any build errors, but it is stopping midway.. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you put your code and logcat?

Comment: @TargetApi(21)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;
    private ScanSettings settings;
    private List<ScanFilter> filters;
    private BluetoothGatt mGatt;

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mHandler = new Handler();
       if(!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "BLE Not Supported",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();}final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =(BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();}

Comment: @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
 startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY) .build();
                filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
            }scanLeDevice(true); }}

Comment: private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    } else {
                        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);

                    }
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
            Log.i("result", result.toString());
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
            connectToDevice(btDevice);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult sr : results) {
                Log.i("ScanResult - Results", sr.toString());
            }
        }

Comment: I am sorry about the way the code looks, I tried to find out how to post code in stackoverflow, but I am unable to find any code " button in my text editor. I am completely new to android, and stack overflow, please help me get this.Sorry for the delay in posting my reply

Comment: private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                     byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.i("onLeScan", device.toString());
                            connectToDevice(device);
                        }
                    });
  }
            };

Comment: public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (mGatt == null) {
            mGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
            scanLeDevice(false);// will stop after first device detection
        }
    }

Comment: private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
  Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "Status: " + status);
  switch (newState) {
  case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
 Log.i("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");
  gatt.discoverServices();
  break;
case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
 Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
 break;
default:
   Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
  }}

Comment: @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
            Log.i("onServicesDiscovered", services.toString());
            gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get
                    (0));
        }

        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
  BluetoothGattCharacteristic
  characteristic, int status) {
 Log.i("onCharacteristicRead", characteristic.toString());
 gatt.disconnect();
 }
    };

Comment: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 215: Landroid/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner;.stopScan (Landroid/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback;)V

Comment: For posting code edit your post and click on {} button por posting code or add 4 blank spaces before every line of code